# problems getting a specific view from a listView in Android

Tags: android, listview

I'm having a hard time getting a specific view, or even row, from a listView. I've read a lot about it, it seems one of the easiest things I've ever done in Android, but it doesn't work and my guess is that there's something trivial that I'm missing.

this is my code for the listView (lvDetail) that is populated by the list "myList":

```
  lvDetail = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.feedlistView);

  lvDetail.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @
    Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      ListData item = myList.get(position);
      Toast.makeText(FeedActivity.this, "You selected : " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      final String TAG = "feed";
      Log.i(TAG, "onItemClick: " + item);
    }
  });

  lvDetail.setAdapter(new MyBaseAdapter(context, myList));
```

when I press everthing (row \ views) nothing happens.
I've tried a million combinations, my guess is that it's something I've missed in the following places, but I've tried a lot of variations and nothing worked:
1. the XML layout, tried using "clickable". didn't work.
2. maybe something in the BaseAdapter I'm using.
3. maybe something with the order of the "setOnItemClickListener" line and the "setAdapter" line.
4. maybe something with implementing something in my FeedActivity activity.
5. maybe something with the "parent" \ "view" in the "onItemClick" line.

please help me figure out what's wrong with my code.

thanks!
Gil.

Comment: is your setOnItemClick is getting callled or not? if not getting called then do you adapter have button, checkbox or any other focusable view?

Comment: Can you show row layout?

Comment: I think that it's not being called for, because I don't see an change in the logcat when I press anywhere in the row.

Comment: the row has buttons, imagebuttons etc. the are defined with a                 android:clickable="true"

Comment: you have issues with those only, remove clickable of the buttons and apply below solution in your project and it will work.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:divider="@null">

Comment: <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:elevation="4dp">

Comment: <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/userpicture"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

Comment: sorry it's too long for a decent copy-paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter xml file write below,

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

and in activity after listview initialization write,

```
 listview.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Accept answer if it worked with your application, thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks! now I can press the whole row, but I can't press a specific button from the row. please help :)

Comment: For specific button press in the row you need to write click listener for button in your adapter class.

Comment: wasn't able to do it. can you please tell me where in the adapter do I put it and in what syntax ?

Comment: Can you please add your adapter class code here so i can help you with code as well.